# How to print last string value of List Array in selenium?

Tags: java, list, selenium, arraylist

There are multiple String element having same xpath. I have store elements in page object model using `List<WebElement>` mechanism. In my test case i want to print last string value of list.

Below is the code of elements stored in repository.

```
public Collection<WebElement> UpdatedMessageList(){
    Collection<WebElement> element=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='msg-paragraph-panel msg-paragraph-msg ng-binding']"));
    return element;
}
```

Can anyone help me to print last string value from my test case?

Answer (score 1):

`findElements` returns a `List`, not just any old `Collection`, so you could use a positional [`get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-):

```
public WebElement UpdatedMessageList(){
    List<WebElement> elements = 
        driver.findElements(By.xpath(
            "//p[@class='msg-paragraph-panel msg-paragraph-msg ng-binding']"));
    if (elements.isEmpty()) {
        return null; // Or throw some meaningful exception
    }
    return elements.get(elements.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: I think elements would be never be null, so just checking it's empty or not is enough.

Comment: @GaurangShah I double checked the [javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-), and you are right - if no elements are found, an empty `List` is returned. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure above code will give you compile error, not sure if you are using Java 9 and something has changed.

Also, Don't use genertic collection class, `findElements` returns `List of WebElements`

```
public WebElement UpdatedMessageList(){
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='msg-paragraph-panel msg-paragraph-msg ng-binding']"));
    return element.get(element.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: Lists use zero-based indexes.